# What does "Security" mean in a GPO for Inbound Firewall Rules?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-10, windows-firewall

My environment is Windows Server 2012 R2 AD DCs with Windows 10 Pro clients.

I have small, simple GPO which sets up Inbound Firewall Rules in:

`Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`

As I said, the rule is pretty simple (allow all incoming for a specific application for TCP and UDP from a specific IP range), but it is not working.

So I was looking at the `Settings` tab in `Group Policy Management` to review exactly what settings were being changed and what might be causing my issue, and there is one setting labeled:

`Security : Require Authentication`

I can't seem to find from where in the `Properties` of the Rule this setting is coming from, and I'm wondering if this might have something to do with why my Rule doesn't seem to work.

Anyone know where this is coming from and/or what it means?

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 1):

The Security setting for the firewall rules is determined by the Action selected for the rule.  This can be specified during rule creation or on the *General* tab of the rule's properties.

Here's a screen shot of the New Inbound Rule Wizard page showing the possible actions with their explanatory text:
[image]

Note specifically that the **Allow the connection** action *includes connections that are protected with IPSec as well as those [that] are not.* In other words, with this rule the authentication requirement is optional. Further, it's my understanding that for authentication to occur in the first place, IPSec must also be configured.  If it is not, Authentication is not required and has no material effect on the rule's operation.

The three possible rule actions correspond to the "Security" setting shown on the Group Policy Management *Settings* tab as follows:

```
Action                                   Security
Allow the connection                     Require authentication
Allow the connection if it is secure     Require authentication and encryption
Block                                    n/a
```

Comment: @Daniel And to answer what is likely your motivation question: Unless you have IPSec configured, the fact your inbound rule says it requires authentication is not the reason it isn't having the desired effect.